# Does stack smashing occur or would this be a format string vulnerability?

Tags: c, security

I am analyzing a code and trying to determine what vulnerability is produced by the code. So far I am thinking it is stack smashing because when typing a password the first time, it is saying it is wrong if it is under 12 characters. When trying another password, even though it is not the correct one, it says it is correct. This would be cause by sizeof(char) function correct? Below is the code I am analyzing:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void detonate_bomb () {
    puts("Approved: bomb detonated!");
    //insert code to detonate the detonate_bomb
    exit(1);
}

#define MAX_INPUT 12
int main() {
    char *key = malloc(MAX_INPUT *sizeof(char));
    strcpy(key, "TiTan15m1D\n");
    while (!feof(stdin)) {
        char *input_pwd = malloc(MAX_INPUT *sizeof(char));
        fgets(input_pwd, MAX_INPUT, stdin);
        if (strcmp(input_pwd, key) == 0)
            detonate_bomb();
        free(input_pwd);
        free(key);
        puts("Wrong password, try again!");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the difference? Aside: please see [Why is `while ( !feof (file) )` always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong). It is better to use the return value from `fgets` to control a loop. You can allocate and free the buffer outside of the loop.

Comment: At the end of the first loop iteration you `free(key)` but continue to dereference it on subsequent loops. Is this a "design plot" of your bomb?

Comment: There is no stack-smashing in this code, so count that out. There is a clear UB from dereferencing a dangling pointer on loop iterations past the first, but those aren't "smashing" anything in the stack (that you know of).

Comment: It would be simpler (and not have to rely on counting characters) to use `char *key = "TiTan15m1D\n";`

Comment: Yes, this is a code given to me to analyze what the memory safety vulnerability is and why it is acting the way it is when entering passwords that don't even match. From what you guys are saying, it would not be stack smashing but rather something like a use-after-free vulnerability because ```free(key)``` is being deallocated too early?

Comment: Yeah, use-after-free is an appropriate description.  An exploit might be based on hoping that on the second iteration, the new input buffer gets allocated at the same address where the key used to be, thus making `strcmp` compare your input string with itself.

Comment: A format string vulnerability occurs when the format string for `printf`,`scanf`, or some similiar function is under the control of the user.  Your program doesn't call any of those functions at all, so it can't possibly have a format string vulnerability.

Comment: Thank you! So to fix this, I would want to eliminate the ```!feof``` function and utilize the ```fgets``` return value for the loop in addition to making sure the ```free(key)``` is allocated at the appropriate time?

Comment: `fgets(input_pwd, MAX_INPUT, stdin);   if (strcmp(input_pwd, key) ...` is also a vulnerability as the return value of `fgets()` was not checked so the memory contents pointed to by `input_pwd` are indeterminant.

Answer (score 0):

There is no format string vulnerability since there are no format strings present.
There is no stack smashing since you don't allocate the buffer data on the stack.

As for what's problematic with the code:

- No checks if `malloc` succeeded.
- Not all necessary header files are included, preventing successful compilation with a standard C compiler.
- Bad use of `feof` - the code should check the result of `fgets` instead. Not checking if `fgets` succeeded is also a vulnerability.
- Blatantly obvious bugs where the program `free` all buffers in the middle of the `while` loop. Both the malloc and the free calls should be moved out of the loop. That is, this program will crash just fine on its own without the help of a malicious user.